# Using "shì" for noun + adjective + noun

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Being a beginner, I am bit puzzled by the concept of "shì" being used not for describing nouns with adjectives.

Using search, I think it is clear to me that:

1. Noun + noun = I can use "shì".
2. Adjective + noun = I should use "hen".

Well but what I am unable to figure out is the combination, like "*This is my new phone*".
I am connecting two nouns, but also connecting an adjective and a noun. What rule is the applied?

Comment: Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Chinese language.

Comment: "This is my new phone", according to usual English grammar, uses "is" to connect a pronoun to a noun phrase. The adjectives "my" and "new" are not being used as predicative adjectives, unlike "red" in "This is red".

Comment: @Pietrossil I don't think you are tactic as to how a language should be learned. It seemed that you don't know what are subjects, objects, possessive particle, modifiers, etc.

Comment: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21853/using-shi4-for-noun-and-adjective-exceptional-rules，Please see this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the answer did not help much, here is mine - it is about predicative and attributive.

*My phone is new.* The adjective describes the subject, this is the predicative.
*My new phone.* The adjective is attributive, it is linked to the noun.

If it is predicative, do not use "to be" (shì).

**SIDE NOTE**: I am a beginner myself and I often see the example "Sky is blue" translated as "Tiānkōng shì lánsè de (天空是蓝色的)". I have no idea why it can be like this as it clearly is predicative.

Comment: Did you mean " If it is attributive, do not use 'to be' (shì)." ? Also, what is so hard to understand about the structure of  "天空(the sky)是(is)蓝色的(blue)"[predicative] /  蓝色的(blue)天空( sky)  [predicative] / 蓝天 (blue sky) [attributive]?

Comment: @TangHo No, shì is not used for predicative adjectives. You are missing the point, you yourself say "Sky IS blue" (noun + adjective) and there is "shì". Why? It is the same as "He IS tall" and there wil not be "shì". For beginners, the basic rule is never to use "shì" to link nouns and adjectives.

Comment: in 天是蓝的, 天 is the [topic], 是蓝的 is [comment/opinion]. [topic]+[comment] structure is a common Chinese sentence structure

Comment: @TryingMyself 天空是蓝色的 sounds like it doesn't make sense if you translate it as "The sky is blue"; the literal translation would be more like "The sky is a blue one". By adding 的 after 蓝色, you create an implied noun; in this context, 蓝色的 really means 蓝色的(天空), but you omit the 天空 because it's already obvious what the meaning is based off of context, acting almost like a pronoun. Thus, you use 是 because you're connecting two noun phrases, 天空 and (蓝色的)天空. If you were to phrase this sentence using 很, it would be written as 天空很蓝 because we're connecting 天空, a noun, with 蓝, an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use your odd rules for English? If not, why invent one for Mandarin? 
"my new phone" is an accusative.  Even "This" is also accusative.

This（这） is（是） my（我的） new phone（新手机/新电话).

shì is mandarin generic connector equivalent to "am/are/is/did/do/does",  but English sometime will omit them.

e.g.

```
"Excuses me, [are] you Mr. John?" -> "请问， 你[是]约翰先生吗？"
"Yes, [I am]" ->  "[是的]" 

You [are] digging your own grave. 
你[这是]找死
你[这是]自掘坟墓
你[这是]作死
你[这是]挖坑给自己跳

[Did he] just wake up?
[他是不是]刚睡醒？

[is he] the person that you speak about?
[他是不是]你刚说的那个家伙？
```

---

hen 很 -  means very , plentiful, a lot

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "noun phrase" instead of "accusative"?

Comment: @Michaelyus  Noun phrase? I wonder how you distinguish `This is my new phone` versus `This is a new phone`?

Comment: All of "this", "my new phone", and "a new phone" can be considered to be [noun phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase), also known as "nominal phrases". In Chinese these are called [名詞句](http://www.cqvip.com/qk/80217x/200406/11456359.html).

Comment: @Michaelyus : Welcome to the confusion of "linguistic" attempt to force English grammar  "noun phrase" into Mandarin, it is AFU . IMO "accusative" (which no longer define in English linguistic usage) is more appropriate and natural definition.

Comment: Someone suggested you use 找死（自掘坟墓）instead of
作死  (ridiculous;reckless). You could consider it.

Comment: I personally like 作死 more because it is widely used in Cantonese while 作死 is mainly Mandarin. Both terms describe someone being reckless (don't think or care about the consequences of one's own words or actions, ) but 找死 fit the English meaning of " digging your own grave" more

Comment: @TangHo :  作死 become general term in modern mandarin. Anyone are welcome to use the longer proverb.

Comment: I meant to write : "作死  is widely used in Cantonese;  while 找死 is mainly Mandarin."

Comment: @TangHo :  MInd the language in literature, PLEASE! 
《红楼梦》第十一回：“ 凤姐儿听了，哼了一声，说道：'这畜生合该`作死`，看他来了怎么样！'”

Comment: First, 红楼梦  is old, the author might not speak Mandarin. Think about it, Tang poems do not rhyme in Mandarin because they were not written in Mandarin. Second, 找死 is much more common than 作死 in Mandarin, that doesn't mean Mandarin speakers do not use 作死. Similarly, 找死 in Cantonese is rarely used,  but it doesn't mean Cantonese people would not say 找死.

Comment: @TangHo  `不作死就不会死 `.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I have your answer.
Shì 是 means 'is' but we tend not to use it with adjectives. That's why you're confused.

I am a teacher - wo shi laoshi

I am fat - wo hen pang

You were right in using 'hen' by the way.

You can use 'shi' but will need to add 'de' at the end

Wo shi pang de - I *am* fat (emphatic, like you are stressing the fact that you are after an argument)

Colours are treated like nouns, so that's the other thing that confused you.

We use the shi...de construction with them:

Wode mao shi heise de - my cat is black

Does that make sense?

G

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a little mistake. It should be:

noun IS noun (period) = noun 是 noun。
noun IS adjective (period) = noun 很 adjective。

When you have: "This is my new phone", basicaly you have "this is my phone" which is a noun (or pronoun actually) IS noun (phone). So it should be 是.

Nota that "new phone" is not a "new + end of the sentence" structure. It's attached to "phone", which is a noun and ends the sentence. That's why it should be 是 and not 很.